# Resizing SVG <path> image to fit 16x16px

Tags: html, css, svg

I got svg triangle as below and i want it to have dimensions 16x16px. No matter what i do it keep to overflow (like puting big image and be able to see only its left top corner. Do you know how to change it via CSS/HTML?

```html
<svg>
  <path d="M 471.253,335.129 272.396,82.226 c -17.417,-30.533 -45.661,-30.533     -63.078,0 L 10.473,335.098 c -3.88,5.533 -8.072,15.41 -8.917,22.117 -2.736,21.738 -4.908,65.18 21.444,65.18 h 435.707 c 26.353,0 24.192,-43.416 21.463,-65.148 -0.844,-6.714 -5.031,-16.579 -8.917,-22.118 z"></path>
</svg>
```

Comment: You'll need a viewBox attribute, and a width attribute: for example `<svg viewBox="0 0 485 485" width="16">`

Answer (score 0):

Your svg file/code missing viewBox atribute
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/viewBox